# How to get BIOS Device Name from Linux, same as Windows Device Manager format

Tags: graphics, pci, display-manager, smbios

My laptop has a display adapter and from Windows 10 I can see its **BIOS Device Name** from..

Device Manager > Display Adapters > Properties > Details > "BIOS device name"

And from there I get a pop up window saying something like: `\_SB.PCI0.GFX0`

How can I get that information if the same laptop is running Linux?

Cheers

### Update

I need this information because I am building a hackintosh and need to build a SSDT to create a display backlight fix. I would like to help out at the [`Opencore project`](https://dortania.github.io/OpenCore-Install-Guide/) and provide a method to do this in Linux as currently [the only method](https://dortania.github.io/Getting-Started-With-ACPI/Laptops/backlight-methods/manual.html) is to switch in to Windows and use `Device Manager`

I tried `dmidecode` and `lspci` and they don't give me a `BIOS device name` in the format that Windows does and is needed to create the SSDT.

I tried [`acpidump`](https://01.org/linux-acpi/utilities) and it's getting me closer but the decompiled output has disassembly errors. It contains the string I am looking for `\_SB.PCI0.GFX0` but I don't know how I would create a script to read that file and correlate it to my particular display adapter. e.g: `Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000`.

These are the commands I have tried so far with `acpidump`
I dump the ACPI tables from my system to a text file:

```
sudo acpidump -o acpidump.out
```

Extract the binary ACPI tables from acpidump output

```
acpixtract -a acpidump.out
```

I now have seven ssdt*.data files. I disassemble the binary table of ssdt1.dat into human source

```
iasl -d ssdt1.dat
```

This gives a large .dsl file, this is just the first 60 lines of over a thousand..

```
/*
 * Intel ACPI Component Architecture
 * AML/ASL+ Disassembler version 20190509 (64-bit version)
 * Copyright (c) 2000 - 2019 Intel Corporation
 * 
 * Disassembling to symbolic ASL+ operators
 *
 * Disassembly of ssdt1.dat, Mon Jun  7 09:54:08 2021
 *
 * Original Table Header:
 *     Signature        "SSDT"
 *     Length           0x00001EED (7917)
 *     Revision         0x01
 *     Checksum         0x9C
 *     OEM ID           "COMPAL"
 *     OEM Table ID     "CRV ORB "
 *     OEM Revision     0x00001000 (4096)
 *     Compiler ID      "ACPI"
 *     Compiler Version 0x00040000 (262144)
 */
DefinitionBlock ("", "SSDT", 1, "COMPAL", "CRV ORB ", 0x00001000)
{
    /*
     * iASL Warning: There was 1 external control method found during
     * disassembly, but only 0 were resolved (1 unresolved). Additional
     * ACPI tables may be required to properly disassemble the code. This
     * resulting disassembler output file may not compile because the
     * disassembler did not know how many arguments to assign to the
     * unresolved methods. Note: SSDTs can be dynamically loaded at
     * runtime and may or may not be available via the host OS.
     *
     * To specify the tables needed to resolve external control method
     * references, the -e option can be used to specify the filenames.
     * Example iASL invocations:
     *     iasl -e ssdt1.aml ssdt2.aml ssdt3.aml -d dsdt.aml
     *     iasl -e dsdt.aml ssdt2.aml -d ssdt1.aml
     *     iasl -e ssdt*.aml -d dsdt.aml
     *
     * In addition, the -fe option can be used to specify a file containing
     * control method external declarations with the associated method
     * argument counts. Each line of the file must be of the form:
     *     External (<method pathname>, MethodObj, <argument count>)
     * Invocation:
     *     iasl -fe refs.txt -d dsdt.aml
     *
     * The following methods were unresolved and many not compile properly
     * because the disassembler had to guess at the number of arguments
     * required for each:
     */
    External (_SB_.PCI0.GFX0, DeviceObj)
    External (_SB_.PCI0.GFX0._DOD, IntObj)
    External (_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.AINT, MethodObj)    // Warning: Unknown method, guessing 2 arguments
    External (_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD01._ADR, IntObj)
    External (_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD01._DGS, IntObj)
    External (_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._ADR, IntObj)
    External (_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL, IntObj)
    External (_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCM, IntObj)
    External (_SB_.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BQC, IntObj)
```

I think maybe I need to dissasemble `ssdt1.dat` such that I don't get disassembly errors and then is there a way to search that disassembled file for a device by a name like 'Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000' or that would at least be obvious this is the `BIOS Device Name` for my display adapter?

Maybe `dmidecode`, `lspci` and `acpidump` can all be combined into a script?

Any other help much appreciated.

Flex

Comment: Not sure if this is different variant to variant .. but on a RHEL machine I get output from `/usr/sbin/dmidecode` - from this article (https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/check-bios-version-linux/)

Comment: `lspci` might be enough. What do you need it for?

Comment: You can get this information by parsing the ACPI DSDT (Differentiated System Description Table)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the best solution or if it will work on every Linux distro but I can find the information I need `\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0` with this command:

```
# cat /sys/class/pci_bus/0000:00/device/0000:00:02.0/firmware_node/path
```

This is also known as the ACPI path. Why does this command work for me?

**Explanation**
In Linux a PCI device is identified with a 16-bit domain number, an 8-bit bus number, a 5-bit device number and a 3-bit function number; the last three numbers are commonly referred to as the device's BDF or B/D/F (for bus/device/function).

The `lspci` command can display this identification number using...

```
# lspci -D
..
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
..
```

The format of this number `0000:00:02.0` is `domain:bus:device:function`.

Now use this command from a Terminal to find the ACPI path of your display adapter

```
# cat /sys/class/pci_bus/<domain:bus>/device/<domain:bus:device:function>/firmware_node/path
```

Again, I don't know much about this topic or if this procedure will work on all distros but it does work on my `Ubuntu mate 20.04.1`.

Another hacky method might be to follow the steps in my initial question with `acpidump`, `acpixtract` and `iasl`. Then just search the resulting disassembled .dsl file for `DeviceObj`. So finding the string: **External (*SB*.PCI0.GFX0, DeviceObj)** would mean the ACPI path is `\_SB_.PCI0.GFX0`

**References**
[Interpreting the output of lspci](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=649b7a71b35fc7ad41e03b6d0e825f07)
[Helpful reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/hackintosh/comments/hdxc2j/acpi_path_via_linux/)